# /wp-admin/plugins.php takes ages to load, and then 404s

Tags: plugins, wp-admin, 404-error

On one of our clients websites, when you try to view the "plugins" page in the back-end, the page loads for several minutes, then returns a 404 (using the WordPress 404 template). This is a project that we inherited, and it's quite a mess; there are around 50 plugins installed, so I'm sure that's eating up a lot of resources.

The file `/wp-admin/plugins.php` definitely exists, so we're very confused how this is returning a 404. It almost seems like it's running out of memory, but if that were the case, wouldn't it error with a 500 instead of 404?

What could be causing this, or what is the recommended method for trying to track this down?

EDIT:

I've installed Query Monitor and Rewrite Rules Inspector, here are my findings:

**Query Monitor**

The plugins page is using up a lot of memory at 40 MB (compared to ~7.3 on one of our more standard sites), but it's nowhere near its limit of 256 MB. Nothing in the data looks egregiously slow, but this issue is intermittent, so I have to wait for it to happen again to be able to test the actual issue.

**Rewrite Rules Inspector**

I see that there are two rules that match for `/wp-admin/plugins.php`; one for "page" and one for "post." The more standard site that I tested on only includes the "page" rule. I've included the table below.

| Rule | Rewrite | Source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `(.?.+?)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$` | `index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]` | `page` |
| `[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$` | `index.php?attachment=$matches[1]` | `post` |

I guess to test this, I could just disable the `.htaccess` rules, so next time this issue crops up (likely tomorrow), I'll give that a try and report back.

**Other Thoughts**

This site uses a caching plugin that I'm not familiar with; W3 Total Cache. As this is another plugin that "rewrites" page contents, could it be that the caching plugin is trying to serve a cached version of `/wp-admin/plugins.php`?

EDIT 2:

I believe I've tracked down the root of the problem: a plugin called GeoDirectory. It's including the rewrite rules which I previously mentioned. I tried to write a rewrite rule with a higher priority as a workaround, but that didn't seem to work.

```
/**
 * Fix PHP files sometimes loading like WordPress pages
 */
function wpd_rewrite_rules(): void {
    add_rewrite_rule("(.*\.php$)", '$matches[1]', "top");
}
add_action("init", "wpd_rewrite_rules", PHP_INT_MAX);
```

This redirect to something like `pagename=wp-admin%2Fplugins.php`, which obviously isn't correct. Is there a way to write a workaround, or should I just try to get in contact with the developer of GeoDirectory to fix this?

Comment: the only scenario I can think of is that you have 2 servers handling the same site but only one of them has a full `wp-admin` folder or even serves WP. Note that it's not the number of plugins that makes a site slow, but rather it's doing a lot of things that makes a site slow. Naturally more plugins do more things but a single plugin or even no plugins and a heavy theme can add all that weight, just as well as a site can be fast with 100 plugins if those plugins are all tiny and lightweight

Comment: It's also useful to know what kind of 404, is it an Nginx/Apache 404 or a WordPress 404 or a CDN 404 etc etc And if it's slow to load what exactly is slow? Lots of DB queries? Making an expensive HTTP request? Be specific! **And remember, this isn't a messageboard/discussion forum, you need a specific question that has all the info needed to answer it, phrased in such a way that you can mark an answer as correct for all people who have that question**. So don't ask open ended questions

Comment: It's on a single server, no fancy load balancing or anything like that. It loads a 404 just like any other 404 on the site, so I'm not sure if that's consider a "WordPress 404" or an "Apache 404" (we do use Apache). I'll see if I can get Query Monitor installed to try and track down some stats, but being unable to access the Plugins page, that's some what difficult (can't use wp-cli unfortunately)

Comment: As far as not asking open ended questions, where would you suggest I go for that instead? I came here because we're stumped.

Comment: it loads a 404 just like any other site could mean literally thousands of things, and you would know if it's a WordPress 404 or an Apache 404. A WP 404 is handled by WP and uses a WP theme etc, an Apache 404 would show either a generic Apache server message or whatever your host has configured it to.

Comment: Yes, then I mean it's a WordPress 404.

Comment: that implies that for that pageload that file does not exist, or that your site is configured to route `wp-admin` requests to the main `index.php` file

Comment: I've added a little more info to my question now that I was able to get some debug tools to work. I'll probably have to follow up again tomorrow, as I can't get the error to occur right now (it's intermittent).

Comment: test with W3 turned off, `wp-admin` shouldn't be triggering rewrite rules as the server should be passing requests directly to it so rewrite rules are never applied

Comment: I think I tracked it down to the plugin "GeoDirectory," updated my question with more info. Currently not experiencing issues, but next time it crops up I'll try with it deactivated.

Comment: If you've singled out a plugin as the cause of your issue, then yes, contact that plugin's support team. If it's happening to you, it's happening to others.